# Extracting List from complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code...

```
        ItineraryViewModel viewModel = new ItineraryViewModel
        {
            Itinerary = itinerary,
            MapModel = new StaticMapModel()
            {
                // GoogleMapType = GoogleMapType.Roadmap,
                // StaticMode = StaticMode.Markers,
                Maps = itinerary.ItineraryDays.FirstOrDefault().Listing.Port.Maps
             }
        };
```

...assigns a single instance of a Map entity to Maps, as is to be expected when using FirstOrDefault. I want, however, to assign a list of maps to Maps but don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: so what is your real question here..? `I am supposed to win the lotto, well at least in my own opinion, but don't know how to achieve this..` do you see the question in my statement..?

Comment: I'll readily admit it's poorly worded, but the lazy self-indulgent sollipsism of a deluded lottery player is not to be found in my question (least I don't think so). If someone works out the answer for me I might upon examining the solutions, be able to reword the original question. I don't think Stackoverflow is designed around this reverse engineering approach to question posing, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
Maps = itinerary.ItineraryDays.Select(id => id.Listing.Port.Maps).ToList();
```

If `Listing.Port.Maps` is a single object.  If it is a collection then you'll want `SelectMany`.